# Rails - return empty json when serializing 'distinct' on single AR column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

My Car model is JSON serialized (class CarSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer). However, for the below controller method, I need only a DISTINCT list of reserve_ids, and if there are none, AR should return empty JSON string/array. I tried testing with `@cars.blank?`  to no avail since nil/empty array isn't return. See below for inspects of the AR object.

```
   def get_reserve_ids

    # @cars.inspect ==> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Car id: nil, car_reserve_id: nil>]>
    @cars = Car.select(:car_reserve_id)
    .where(client_id: current_user.client_id).distinct

    # @cars.inspect ==> [nil]
    # @cars = Car.select(:car_reserve_id)
    # .where(client_id: current_user.client_id).map(&:car_reserve_id).uniq

    logger.debug @cars.inspect

    render json: @cars, only: [:car_reserve_id]

  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `@cars.compact` — it will remove all nulls from array, so you will return an empty array.

Comment: Worked with using `.map` option!! Now I'm able to test `if @cars.blank? render :json => [], status: :ok else ...`. Thank you - much appreciated!!